# how to show that a function is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

How to prove that the function $f:(0,2)\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded.

I know for a function is unbounded if: $\forall M>0 \exists x\text{ such that }|f(x)|>M$

Comment: For $n\ne0$, $1/(1/n)=n$.

Comment: That looks like a definition of boundedness looks weird to me, there's both a $\forall$ and a $exists$ for $x$, and only having a condition saying $f$ is larger then something makes it look more like a condition for unboundedness.

Comment: yea that was a condition for boundedness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was bounded by, let us say, $C$, then
$$
\left| x \frac{1}{x} \right| \leq C |x|,
$$
and hence $\lim_{x \to 0} 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty $$
therefore 
$$\forall M\geq 0, \exists  \delta>0: |x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|> M$$

in particular
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N, \exists x_n: |f(x_n)|>n$$
therefore $f$ is unbounded.