# Finding functions that satisfy a particular differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, continuity, solution-verification

Suppose $y(x) = x^2$ is a solution of $y"+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0 $ on (0,1) where $P$ and $Q$ are continuous functions on $(0,1)$. Can both $P$ and $Q$ be bounded functions? Justify your answer.

I have tried differentiating $y=x^2$ , $y'=2x$ and $y'/x=2$. Differentiating this once again yielded $y"-y'/x=0$. So I don't think $P(x)$ can be bounded in  $(0,1)$.
But Iam not so sure about whether this is correct or not.
So it would be great if anyone has some ideas to share.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Edited that part.

Comment: [e](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090646/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-unbounded) question help cheyuvarikum. Idea enna vecha, namale unbounded ayute assume cheyuvange oru contradiction ketum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you ask can be rewritten as : can one find $P, Q$ bounded continuous functions such that :

$$ 2 + 2 x P(x) + x^2 Q(x) = 0 $$

for $x \in (0, 1)$.

Letting $x \to 0$ and assuming by contradiction that $P$ and $Q$ are bounded, you find $2 = 0$, so it cannot hold.

The reasoning you were doing had the right idea but in this kind of problem (proving something cannot exist) a useful method is to prove it by contradiction (indeed assuming something exists usually gives a lot of possibilities).